Iterating over a list?
List measurements_list contains integers read from input, representing data samples from an experiment. For each element in measurement_list:
•If the element's value is less than or equal to 40, then output 'Sample', followed by the element's index, and 'is accepted'.
•Otherwise, increment num_rejected and output 'Sample', followed by the element's index, and 'is rejected'.
I want to compare solutions, I haven't figured it out yet

const measurements_list: number[] = [10, 20, 50, 5];
let num_rejected: number = 0;

measurements_list.forEach((value: number, index) => {

    if (value <= 40) {
        console.log(`Sample ${index} is accepted`)
        return;
    }

    num_rejected++;
    console.log(`Sample ${index} is rejected`) 

});

